# How to remove hyphens from all the xml document with xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Im really new with XSLT and I want to remove all the hyphens in my XML, whether it is in the attribute value or in text, I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION name="-001">
    <THINGS>
        <THING evaluationZ="-29" evaluationY="226" action="-MOVE" name="-XYZ">
            <CT>
                <work task="1">-ALL </work>
                <work task="2">-HIGH</work>
                <work task="3">-FAST</work>
                <work task="4">DET</work>
                <work task="5">-COMPLETE</work>
                <work task="6">-FINISH</work>
            </CT>
            <VAC>
                <days amount="0"/>
                <days amount="2"/>
            </VAC>
        </THING>
    <THINGS>
</SECTION>
```

And I want this at the output, exactly the same but without any hyphen :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION name="001">
    <THINGS>
        <THING evaluationZ="29" evaluationY="226" action="MOVE" name="XYZ">
            <CT>
                <work task="1">ALL </work>
                <work task="2">HIGH</work>
                <work task="3">FAST</work>
                <work task="4">DET</work>
                <work task="5">COMPLETE</work>
                <work task="6">FINISH</work>
            </CT>
            <VAC>
                <days amount="0"/>
                <days amount="2"/>
            </VAC>
        </THING>
    <THINGS>
</SECTION>
```

I have this XSLT, but its not working

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'- ','')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

how can I write the XSLT to achieve what is described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-','')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-','')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will not copy comments or processing instructions.

Comment: there is a way to translate more than one characters? Now I need to translate ALL by ANY, DET by PRT, Im trying something like this but it give a wrong output.               
          `<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-','')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'ALL','ANY')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'DET','PRT')"/>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `<xsl:template match="/">`, you need one template that transforms text content and one that transforms attributes:

```xml
<xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-','')"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*" priority="1">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-','')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

With these `priority` attributes, you can keep the `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">`.

Comment: You also need a template to copy elements and apply templates to their children.

Comment: *"Keep the `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">`"*. No, that is wrong. You will get a conflict with both of your added templates and depend on the processor's willingness to recover (which it will do correctly only if the identity transform template happens to be the first one).